# Reading files common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, lispworks

I'm a newbie in common lisp, i want to do some (maybe advanced file reading)

so lets say i have example1.txt, example2.txt and example3.txt.

example1.txt has the following:

> Born  9 October 1940
>
> Died  8 December 1980 (aged 40)
>
> John Winston Ono Lennon, MBE (born John Winston Lennon; 9 October 1940
>   – 8 December 1980) was an English musician, singer and songwriter who
>   rose to worldwide fame as a founder member of the Beatles

so what i want to do is:

i get prompted to enter a name, I enter Lennon.

if the file contains the word lennon, keep reading, else read example2, I don't know how to use the buffer in LISP, in C++ or perl, that'd be so easy for me and wouldn't had asked this question, but i have to do it in lisp. I want to return the index of the element as well so for example, if i typed "musician" i want it to continue reading, and not to start from 0.

according to [this book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html) i may need a function called `READ-SEQUENCE` is that true? and how to use it? by the way, I'm on windows and using LispWorks.

Comment: not a homework, and this is the first time i use lisp, what I'm trying to do is far more complicated than this question so i tried to keep it simple :) what could i possibly add to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: I'd go with `read-line` and `search` I guess. But it might also depends on what will be the further use of the application. Some times a system call to `grep` could be preferable, or maybe you'd need a library to deal with natural language processing... Is this something specific to LispWorks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun find-word-in-file (word file)
  (with-open-file (stream file)
    (loop
       :for line := (read-line stream nil nil)
       :for found := (and line (search word line))
       :until (or (not line) found)
       :summing (length line) :into position
       :finally (return (when found (+ position found))))))

(find-word-in-file "Lennon" "./example.txt")

;; 79
```

Something like this would do, I guess.